# What does "-" means in this declaration

Tags: ryz

I was looking at this source code and in the attributes declaration there is a minus sign.

```
- s : String
```

Or in a method declaration:

```
- x( aPoint : Point ):Integer {
     ad : Double = aPoint.getX()
     ad.intValue()
  }
```

What does it stands for?

Comment: and by the way what does you tag mean?

Comment: Nevermind, OP answered in another comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes the definition private, according to the access modifiers list.

http://code.google.com/p/ryz/wiki/RyzLanguageReference#Methods

Answer (score 0):

means s or x aren't static members, if you put `+` that means they are static ones

Answer (score -1):

From [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C), minus signs denote instance methods.

Comment: its Ryz, not Objective-c. its a JVM language.

Comment: The tag previously stated objective c. It has now been changed.

Comment: My bad.  I'm pretty sure it said objective-c when I answered it.  :-)

Comment: Ahh no worries, I've had that myself!